# Random element of derived group can be written as product of at most $n^3$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $[G:Z(G)] = n$ and let D be the set of all commutators $[g,h]$ with $g,h \space \epsilon G$ (not the derived group, just the set of commutators). Then : $\vert D \vert \leq n^2$. Now I must show that every element of $G'$ can be written as the product of at most $n^3$ elements from D. This has to be an easy proof, using the pigeonhole principle, but I don't see how to make it work. How should I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $(G:Z(G))=n$ there are at most $n^2$ different commutators. Furthermore in any product of commutators any two factors may be brought together by replacing
the intermediate factors by conjugates, also commutators. Hence it suffices to show that the $(n+1)$-th power of a commutator is the product of $n$ commutators. But if $a,b\in G$, then $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^n$ is central, so that
$$
(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^n = b^{-1}(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^nb(aba^{-1}b^{-1}),
$$
which may be written as 
$$
b^{-1}\left( (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{n-1}(ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2}\right)b
$$
and thus is a product of $n$ commutators, as required.

Comment: Why are there at most $n^2$ different commutators?

Comment: Because there are $n$ residue classes $\overline{g}$ modulo center, hence at most $n^2$ different commutators $[\overline{g},\overline{g'}]$. Now write $\overline{g}=gz$ with a central element. You have stated this by saying that we know $|D|\le n^2$.